# Flexbox - center vertically second row

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment, centering

I'd like to position second row in the center of container, but I can't figure out how to make it. `align-self` works in horizontal direction only - even if `flex-direction` is set to "column".

```css
.first, .second {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.first {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.second {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: purple;
}

.container {
  background-color: silver;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    first
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    second
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First try with the  `margin: auto 0` but it also takes into account the first one.

Comment: I think all what you need is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties/33856609#33856609

Comment: Or just remove `flex-direction: column` & `align-self: center`, same result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normally you could set the vertical margins of the element with the class of `.second` to auto to center it but, the element with the class of `.first` pushes the centered element down just off center. You can fix this by setting a `transform: translateY(-50%)` on the centered element.

```css
.first,
.second {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.first {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.second {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: purple;
  margin: auto 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.container {
  background-color: silver;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    first
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    second
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only works properly if the second element is exactly the same height as the first.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see what is actually happening because the width of `.first` and `.second` are set to 100%. If you make them 50x50 squares you can see that align-self works on the cross-axis of the parent container so in this case it makes `.second` horizontally centered.

A solution that could work is to nest another flexbox within .second like so: https://jsfiddle.net/Lygdk4xo/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind add a third blank div. You can center the second div by setting `justify-content` to `space-between`.

```css
.first,
.second,
.third {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-color: silver;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.second {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    first
  </div>

  <div class="second">
    second
  </div>

  <div class="third">
  </div>
</div>
```